# How to use the PrepareForSegue method to transfer an object which has an unknown type in the receiving controller?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I'm working on Xcode projects in Swift and I'm trying to transfer data from a "FirstViewController" to a "SecondViewController".

First of all, I receive some data by my user in the FirstViewController. I made a structure to put all these data in one single object that i try to transfer.

Here's my code :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToSecondViewController" {
            let sentData:typeOfMyStrcuture = myObject()
            let secondVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
            secondVC.sentData = sentData
        }
    }
```

In my SecondViewController I have :

```
var sentData: typeOfMyStructure!
```

The problem is : since the type of the object i'm sending is unknown in my SecondViewController, i got the following error : "Cannot find type 'typeOfMyStructure' in scope".
I tried to write the same structure in my SecondViewController for it to recognize the type but I get this error : "Cannot assign value of type 'FirstViewController.typeOfMyStructure' to type 'SecondViewController.typeOfMyStructure'

Thanks by advance for your precious help !

Comment: You declared `typeOfMyStructure`struct inside the `FirstViewController`? It should be on the same level.

Comment: Yes ! My structure is declared inside the FirstViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. if `typeOfMyStructure` is created inside the first view controller declare in the second view controller

   ```
   var sentData: FirstViewController.typeOfMyStructure!
   ```
2. Declare `typeOfMyStructure` outside of any view controller

Side note: Please name structs and classes with a starting capital letter

Comment: Thanks ! Your first option worked. I'll remember to call my original ViewController before giving the type !

And thanks for your piece of advice about the first capital letter in declaring a structure or class name. I'm beginning and every piece of knowledge is useful !!!

Thanks a lot !